# Change dataframe schema from narrow one to full

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's assume, that I have following dataset:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      0 |      1 | 0.15   |  2.132 |
|      1 |      2 | 0.72   |   0.15 |
|      2 |     12 | error  |        |
|      3 |     75 | error  |        |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

As You can see, **field3** may contain `double` or `string` values. Only possible `string` value here is **error**. In case of `error` value **field4** doesn't contain any value at all(in fact there is 15 fields after **field3** which I omitted for readability sake and for them apply the same rule)

So I'm trying accomplish the following:

1. Read input with narrow schema(which contains description only for first three fields)
2. Filter erroneous
3. Apply new schema, which consist of all the fields

So, reading looks like this:

```scala
val er_schema = 
  StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("field1", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("field2", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("field3", StringType, true)))

val c_schema = 
  StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("field1", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("field2", IntegerType, true),
      // StringType only for now, DoubleType would be used instead
      StructField("field3", StringType, true),
      StructField("field4", StringType, true)))

val raw = sc.read.schema(er_schema).csv(PATH)
val correctOnly = filterErr(raw)
ss.createDataframe(
  correctOnly,
  c_schema))
```

This code falling with exception: **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3**

As I understand it's because underlying RDD consists only of 3 first fields.

So, here is the question: Is it possible to use narrowed(In the meaning of reduced number of fields) schema and then convert dataframe to normal(containing of all the fields) schema?

**EDIT 1:** The source file is in `CSV` format and looks like this:

```
0,1,0.15,2.132
1,2,0.72,0.15
2,12,error
3,75,error
```

Possible solution which comes to my mind is to use RDD and apply full schema after filtering erroneous rows, but I wonder is it possible to acomplish by only using of dataframes

**EDIT 2:**
What I want as result:

Correct one:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|      0 |      1 | 0.15   |  2.132 |
|      1 |      2 | 0.72   |   0.15 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

With correct data types(fields `field3` and `field4` as DoubleType)

**EDIT 3:** Main issue here is with `field3` column - it can contain not only `double` values, but also `strings`. I want to get rid of rows with `string` values and preserve only with double values. I tried to use two different schemas but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just from the quick thought i got, What if you have two data frames one for the correct fields and one with the error in it, for the error df you can add the columns matching to the correct df and pass a static value and at the end union both the data frames.  I'm putting this thought here because you want to do it only from data frames.

Comment: @roh Thanks for Your reply. Unfortunately, my goal is to get only "correct" fields(which doesn't have 'error' value in 3d column)

Comment: Why don't filter? Meaning `Dataframe.where(col("field3") =!= lit("error"))` ?

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan Thanks for Your reply. Unfortunately the issue here isn't in filtering, but with preserving correct datatypes. Field3 may contain not only doubles, but also strings, and I want somehow filter these rows so result would have only double types rows

Comment: 1) Filter field3, then you fill have only needed rows(you can apply UDF for that row to execute some compex logic to check value - try to parse it as double)

2) Use withColumn to create new column and cast it to needed type

3) drop original column.

I can write an example if it's not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop rows that do not follow a specified schema by setting the [`mode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-scala.collection.Seq-) to `DROPMALFORMED`. When reading the data, use the schema of the dataframe you want:

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("field1", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("field2", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("field3", DoubleType, true),
  StructField("field4", DoubleType, true)
))
```

Then read the csv file:

```
val df = spark.read.
  .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv("/path/to/file")
```

In this way, all rows that do not have the correct data type or wrong number of rows will be discarded.